# Easy Rails question re: displaying data in secondary table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-tables

Easy for anyone but this newbie, I'm sure, but I can't find the answer anywhere. I have a User model and a Role model, with role_id in the users table; I want to show the actual role (Admin, Visitor, etc) which resides in the roles table, on my users index page.
The pertinent section of the index.html.erb:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.username %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.role_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

So what do I put in place of user.role.id?

role.rb:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :role
end
```

I'm using Rails 3, fwiw.

TIA

Comment: is this a has_one or a has_many relationship?

Comment: what are the properties of the role model?

Comment: edit: added role and user model code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models are indeed configured incorrectly, but from what I can understand of the question you want the following.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

And then you can do the following:

```
<%= user.role.name_field %>
```

This will allow multiple Users to all have the same role. Instead of enforcing a one to one relationship. No schema change is needed.